# How to update CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE time values in docker container?

Tags: django, docker, celery, celerybeat

The site is deployed on Django. Docker is used.
I decided to change the time for tasks, but unfortunately their execution itself does not work according to the new time. Only the old time works.
I decided to install a nano editor in the container, looked at what was in the settings, and everything was as it should be, ran the docker-compose up --build command, which did not help either.
Celery-Beat launched, Celery too. Redis works.

I also deleted the celerybeat-schedule.
Most importantly, I see that it changes at given new intervals of time

settings.py

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
"controller": {
    "task": "modules.parser.tasks.parser_driver_task",
    "schedule": crontab(minute=5),
},
"updater": {
    "task": "modules.parser.tasks.updater_driver_task",
    "schedule": crontab(minute=10),
},
"clean_hits": {
    "task": "modules.core.tasks.clean_hits",
    "schedule": crontab(minute=0, hour=0),
},
"clean_loads": {
    "task": "modules.core.tasks.clean_loads",
    "schedule": crontab(minute=1, hour=0, day_of_month='1'),
},
"clean_sessions": {
    "task": "modules.core.tasks.clean_sessions",
    "schedule": crontab(minute=2, hour=0, day_of_month='1'),
},
"db_backup": {
    "task": "modules.core.tasks.db_backup",
    "schedule": crontab(minute=5, hour=0),
},
}
```